Attempted solution for convergence of a recursive sequence
This exercise is according to text book “Understanding Analysis” authored by Stephen Abbott.
I would like advice for improving the proof-writing and “where it can be improved” also if there is flaw on my solution for each subproblem.
Because of that I am kind of being isolated at school, please also indicate if the format of my proof is meeting the standard of university level mathematics, in terms of terminology (I actually am so cornered that I have no friend, even teacher wont respond to me)
Thanks so much
{Exercise 2.4.1}
Prove the sequence defined with $x_1=3$ converges:
\begin{equation}
    x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{4-x_n}
\end{equation}
(1): Show that the recursive relation converges
(2): Explain why $\lim\{x_{n+1}\}=\lim\{x_n\}$
(3): Taking the limit on both sides of the recursive relation and compute $\lim\{x_n\}$
(i)
Claim that $x_n$ is decreasing monotonically for all $n>1$
The base case holds true obviously
Let $x_n=\frac{1}{4-x_{n-1}}$
We assume that $x_{n}-x_{n-1}<0 $ is a proven statement for some $n>1$
It follows that:
\begin{equation}
    \frac{1}{4-x_n}-\frac{1}{4-x_{n-1}}<0
\end{equation}
Through rearrangement:
\begin{equation}
    x_{n-1}-x_{n}>0
\end{equation}
By induction it shows that the sequence indeed decreases monotonically for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$
We also want to show that $x_n$ is bounded, since $x_n$ is decreasing it is bounded above, for showing that $x_n$ is indeed bounded below:
We claim for the sake of contradiction that there exists some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x'_n<0$ then it follows $x_n>x_{n+1}$ implying $0>\frac{1}{4-x'_{n}}>0$ which contradicts the monotonicity of $x_n$
Since it is bounded and decreasing, invoking the monotone convergence we have thus proven that $x_n$ converges.
(ii)
Let $A:=\bigg\{x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{4-x_n}|n\in\mathbb{N}\bigg\}$
Since $A$ is nonempty set, and bounded below, by the axiom of completeness, there exists a greatest lower bound. Since $x_n$ is monotone, as $n$ tends infinity, the distance between $x_n$ and the infimum is then arbitrary small, thus:
\begin{equation}
    \lim\{x_{n+1}\}=\lim\{x_n\}
\end{equation}
(iii)
By equation (4) we know the limit tends the same value, we define:
\begin{equation*}
    x_n=x_{n+1}=L \ \Rightarrow L=\frac{1}{4-L}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    L(4-L)=1  \Rightarrow (L-2)^2=3 
\end{equation*}
Which implies $L=2+\pm{\sqrt{3}}$  Since  $2+\sqrt{3}>x_n$ which does not suffice as the infimum, it follows the infimum of $x_n$ as $n$ tends infinity is $L=2-\sqrt{3}$

I don't care for the line "through rearrangement."  I think it is cleaner to show the algebra.  It does depend on the fact that $(4-x_n) > 0.$  Which is true based on the assumption, but I would say it explicitly.
